# Can someone please explain classes MA and AM (with an example)? What happens to AM in case of PH[2]=PSPACE?

Tags: complexity-theory

I am trying to understand two player (prover-Merlin and verifier-Arthur) interactive proof complexity classes and had a few doubts.

As I understand, the classes $MA$ and $AM$ involve two players, where Merlin tries to convince Arthur about solution to a problem by sending messages such that if the proof is correct Merlin can convince Arthur with high probability and if incorrect there is no such proof possible that can convince Arthur with high probability. But I am unclear about the technical details about the kind of messages they are allowed to exchange (there is some mention about coin tosses but I am not much clear about that).

1. What is the difference b/w $MA$ and $AM[2]$? Can someone please provide an example of the problem in each classes, walk through/explain them?
2. I understand the class $PSPACE$. Its known that:

- $AM[poly(n)]=PSPACE$
- $AM[k] \subseteq \Pi^p_2$.
- $MA \subseteq \Sigma^p_2 \cap\Pi^p_2$.

  Hypothetically, if its proven that $PSPACE=\Sigma^p_2$. This would imply that:
- $AM[k] \subseteq (AM[poly(n)]=\Sigma^p_2 =PSPACE)$

  would this result help tighten the equivalence/identity in any way, i.e. does the number of messages still remain $poly(n)$ or can we reduce them to linear or logarithmic in the new identity? Can we say anything new at all due to the above collapse?

Comment: can someone please comment?